# Nginx Passenger restart issue

Tags: nginx, passenger

I have passenger and nginx installed on ubuntu 10.04.

this is how my virtual host config looks like.

```
server {
listen 80 default;
server_name www.domain.com;
root /rails_app/public;
passenger_enabled on;
}
```

when i try to start nginx I get the following error.

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available $ 
=>sudo service nginx restart
Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "passenger_enabled" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/001admin.domain.com:5
```

What Have I missed here. What is the issue?

Thanks
    nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Comment: Did you load module or compile with support `--add-module=/usr/share/passenger/ngx_http_passenger_module`?

Answer (score 3):

This simply means that nginx was compiled without Phusion Passenger support. You need to recompile it with or find RPM/Deb packet for your distro and install it into system.

*Please, follow these instructions to install Passenger module* [http://www.modrails.com/install.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20120123091157/http://www.modrails.com/install.html)

Comment: thats what I did in the first place. I get this error after passenger-install-nginx-module. Is there any other possible reason for this error?
thanks

Comment: According to your config your NGINX compiled without passenger support. This is a very good "how to" , follow this, and it sould help you http://extralogical.net/articles/howto-compile-nginx-passenger.html

Comment: Don't you just love these "I have solved this but I will not say how I did it" type of post?

Answer (score -1):

Did you install nginx prior to installing passenger? I encountered this issue on 16.04 and resolved it by `sudo apt-get purge nginx` followed by `sudo apt-get install nginx`. After, I just had to uncomment the `# include /etc/nginx/passenger.conf;` in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

Answer (score -4):

```
nginx version: nginx/0.7.65
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --with-debug --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_realip_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-ipv6 --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-0.7.65/modules/nginx-upstream-fair
```

Comment: @Sergei Lomakov This is nginx -v

Comment: What is this? This is not an answer.

Comment: This is the original poster trying to expand their question by adding more information (e.g. `nginx -v` in this case)